# ディレクトリにあるサイズの大きなファイル以外を一覧取得したい

Tags: shellscript

`~/Downloads`フォルダに存在するファイルのうち10M以上のサイズのファイル以外をすべて一覧で取得したいです

可能ならば、`~/Downloads/example-dir/*`のように再帰的にすべてのファイルの一覧を取得したい

Comment: `$ find ./Downloads -size -5M`のようにしたら解決しました。
`$ find ./Downloads -size -5M | grep pdf`などするとpdfのみの検索も可能になるようですね。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

文字通り「サイズ10M以上のファイル以外」であれば、こうですね。これではディレクトリなども含まれます:

```
$ find ~/Downloads ! -size +10M
```

「サイズ 10M以下のファイル」なら:

```
$ find ~/Downloads -size -10M -type f
```

さらに「*.pdfのみ」という条件を加えるなら:

```
$ find ~/Downloads -size -10M -type f -name "*.pdf"
```

Comment: コロンブスの卵だ。驚きました(´・ω・｀)